# Why I cannot access beyond the root directory in IIS on Windows 10?

Tags: wordpress, iis, window

I've just migrated my local WordPress sites to a new machine and I now can't browse past the root directory.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro x64

My IIS wwwroot folder is mapped to `E:\InetPub`

`http://localhost/index.html` works just fine for asp, PHP etc

`E:\InetPub\localpress`

`http://localhost/localpress/index.html` gives me HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

[image]
I've checked all manner of properties and setting but can find nothing wrong/different between my old machine and this machine. I've checked many articles to see if I have missed something.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to include the whole 500.19 error page. There isn't anything more useful than that page.

Comment: `0x8007000d` almost always points to missing OOB components https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: I found that your request url is http://localhost/localpress, without index.html. Do you use url rewrite rule? There are many errors that cause 500.19, usually caused by URL rewriting module (referenced in web.config) is missing or proper version is not installed. you can install URL rewriting module via web platform installer, and I recommend to check all dependencies from web.config and install them.